# How to stop drag and drop of tabpages?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tabcontrol

How do I maintain fixed tab index of Tab Control so that user need not move tabs from one position to another from their default position. (Draging a tab from one position and place at some other location).

Answer (score -1):

set canReorderTab property to false.

```
tabControl.CanReorderTabs = false;
```

Comment: This is not WinForms or WPF, this is a custom GUI component. Your question is misleading.